# Reverted PNG Textures with Metal, when compiled with Macos SDK 10.14

Tags: macos, png, metal, macos-mojave, metalkit

I have a very strange problem, which I did not find mentioned anywhere. My company develops plugins for various hosts. Right now we are trying to move our OpenGL code to Metal. I tried with some of hosts (Like Logic and Cubase), and, it worked. Here is the example:

[image]

However, recently, new versions of those apps became available, compiled with 10.14 MacOS SDK, and here is what I started to get:

[image]

So, we have 2 problems: Color and Flipped textures. I found a solution for color (see code below), but I have absolutely no idea how to solve textures problem! I can, of course, flip the textures, but then on the previous app versions, they will become corrupt.

I believe that something has change in PNG loading, since, if you look carefully - text textures, that are generated on the fly, look the same in both occasions.

Here is my code:

```
imageOptions = @{MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB : @FALSE}; // Solves the color problem
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:imageBuffer length:imageBufferSize];
requestedMTLTexture = [m_metal_renderer.metalTextureLoader newTextureWithData:imageData options:imageOptions error:&error];
```

while imageData is a memory where PNG is placed. I also tried this approach:

```
CGDataProvider* imageData = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nullptr, imageBuffer, imageBufferSize, nullptr);
CGImage* loadedImage = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imageData, nullptr, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
requestedMTLTexture = [m_metal_renderer.metalTextureLoader newTextureWithCGImage:loadedImage options:0 error:&error];
```

And got EXACTLY the same result.

The issue is happening with all applications built with the latest, 10.14 SDK on 10.14 OS. Does anyone have a clue what causes it, or at least, give me a way to understand what SDK I was compiled with?

Comment: Your textures are flipped, you need to translate by the height of the image and flip the sign of the Y axis. Also, you need to read the textures as BGRA to avoid the problem you are seeing with the B and R channels being backwards. Don't use the metal texture loader just use the CoreGraphics APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

[MTKTextureLoaderOptionOrigin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtktextureloaderoptionorigin?language=objc) a key used to specify when to flip the pixel coordinates of the texture.

If you omit this option, the texture loader doesn’t flip loaded textures.

This option cannot be used with block-compressed texture formats, and can be used only with 2D, 2D array, and cube map textures. Each mipmap level and slice of a texture are flipped.

```
imageOptions = @{MTKTextureLoaderOptionSRGB : @FALSE, MTKTextureLoaderOptionOrigin : @TRUE}; // Solves the color problem
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:imageBuffer length:imageBufferSize];
requestedMTLTexture = [m_metal_renderer.metalTextureLoader newTextureWithData:imageData options:imageOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: I tried it. With all 3 possible values. It's either flips the textures regardless the application or leaves them as is.